# syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: c

Below is my code, it keeps telling me that line 10 is causing this "syntax error near unexpected token `('" but I cannot figure out why.  I am adding to a code that was already written but the part where it says there is an error is not part of what I added.  So I'm very confused about why I'm getting this error.  Also I would like a good definition of what this error actually means.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "applanix_data.h"
#include "applanix_pos_out.h"

#define DEGREES2RADIANS  (3.141592654 / 180.0)

int output_group_1(FILE *fp,     /* This is line 10 */
               FILE *fpout,
               unsigned short myyear,
               unsigned short mymonth,
               unsigned short myday,
               double time_sod,
               double double_time_met)
{
struct applanix_data_group1 data1;
struct pospacsbet sbet;

if(fread(&data1,sizeof(struct applanix_data_group1),1,fp)==1)
 {
    sbet.gpstime = time_sod;
    sbet.latitude = data1.latitude * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.longitude = data1.longitude * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.altitude = data1.altitude;
    sbet.x_velocity = data1.eVelocity;
    sbet.y_velocity = data1.nVelocity;
    sbet.z_velocity = data1.dVelocity;
    sbet.roll = data1.aircraftRoll * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.pitch = data1.aircraftPitch * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.platform_heading = data1.aircraftHeading * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.wander_angle = data1.aircraftWanderAngle * DEGREES2RADIANS;
    sbet.x_body_acceleration = data1.aircraftTransverseAcceleration;
    sbet.y_body_acceleration = data1.aircraftLongitudinalAcceleration;
    sbet.z_body_acceleration = data1.aircraftDownAcceleration;
    sbet.x_body_angular_rate = data1.aircraftAngularRateAboutDownAxis;
    sbet.y_body_angular_rate = data1.aircraftLongitudinalAcceleration;
    sbet.z_body_angular_rate = data1.aircraftAngularRateAboutDownAxis;

    if(fwrite(&sbet,sizeof(struct pospacsbet),1,fpout)!=1)
      {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error writing POSPAC SBET output!\n");
         exit(-2);
      }

    sbet.latitude1 = sbet.latitude * (180/3.141592654);
    sbet.longitude1 = sbet.longitude * (180/3.14592654);
    sbet.day = sbet.gpstime/86400;
    sbet.time = sbet.gpstime/86400;
    sbet.hour1 = (sbet.time - sbet.day);
    sbet.hour = sbet.hour1*24;
    sbet.time = sbet.hour1*24;
    sbet.minute1 = (sbet.time - sbet.hour);
    sbet.minute = sbet.minute1*60;
    sbet.time = sbet.minute1 * 60;
    sbet.second1 = (sbet.time - sbet.minute);
    sbet.second = sbet.second1*60;


    printf("%12.8f, %12.8f, %6.3f, %i:%i:%4.2f\n",sbet.longitude1,sbet.latitude1,sbet.altitude,sbet.hour, sbet.minute, sbet.second);
    return 0;
 }
 else
  return -1;
}
```

*Editing the OP's comment into the question*:

```
unix> g++ applanixraw2out.c
unix> ./applanixraw2out.c applanix_raw_20120508.bin > test.txt
./applanixraw2out.c: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token ('
```

Comment: There probably is a bug at the end of `applanix_pos_out.h`.

Comment: The error is before this code. I've just compiled this with `clang -Wall -c` and it compiled fine, without any errors or warnings.

Comment: Its not when i compile it that i get the error, it is when i try to run it

Comment: @user2718341 huh? Does your program really output `syntax error near unexpected token '('`? It rather seems like a compiler error.

Comment: unix>  g++ applanixraw2out.c
unix> ./applanixraw2out.c applanix_raw_20120508.bin > test.txt
./applanixraw2out.c: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./applanixraw2out.c: line 10: `int output_group_1(FILE *fp,'

Comment: @H2CO3: It's not a compiler error, it's a shell error. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson Uh-huh. That's tough. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

That's not a compiler syntax error, it's a shell error.

You're trying to execute your C source code directly.  The system is assuming the file is a shell script.

You need to compile it to an executable, and then run the executable:

```
$ gcc applanixraw2out.c -o applanixraw2out
$ ./applanixraw2out [arguments]
```

In a comment, you said you did the following:

```
unix> g++ applanixraw2out.c
unix> ./applanixraw2out.c applanix_raw_20120508.bin > test.txt
./applanixraw2out.c: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token ('
```

The `g++` command is for C++ code; your code is C, so you should use `gcc` instead.

You have to specify the name of the executable file, which is most commonly the source file name with `.c` removed.  If you don't, both `g++` and `gcc` produce an executable named `a.out` by default (for historical reasons). Use the `-o` option to override that default.

Also, in order to get that syntax error you must have done something like:

```
$ chmod +x applanixraw2out.c
```

Setting execute permission on files that aren't meant to be executed is [mostly harmless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Mostly_Harmless), but should be avoided since it can make errors like this more difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1):

As [starblue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49246/starblue) mentioned in his comment, check the code in the two included header files.  The error message should tell you exactly where the error occurred.  Look at the line or two *before* the line listed in the error and make sure the syntax is correct.  This error is almost always caused by a missing `;`, `(`, `{`, etc on a preceding line.

Comment: Good guess, but that's not it; see my answer.

Comment: To be fair, this was posted *before* we realized that the poster was trying to run the source code directly.